# get relatinal column HasManyThrough, set in response

Tags: laravel, has-many-through

i have craete membership that user can purchase one time of get all users with their membership and when they have purchase and when expired i'm confuse with this how to get my table structure is as:

User Model:

```
id
membership_id

public function membership() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Membership::class);
}
```

Order:

```
id
user_id

public function item() {
    return $this->hasOne(OrderItem::class, 'order_id', '_id');
}
```

order_item:

```
order_id
membership_id
created_at
expiration_date

public function membership() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Membership::class, 'membership_id', '_id');
}

public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id', '_id');
}
```

membership:

```
id
name
type
```

I want get data on time of listing like this how to load relation:

```
user{
name
email
membership{
        name
        type
        order_item{
                 expiration_date
                 created_at
                 }
           }
}
```

Comment: It would be also simple if you have created `membership` relation with `order_item`. If you have one then let me know. Like membership `hasOne` or `hasMany` relationship with `order_items`

Comment: yes i have belongsTo relation in order_items.

Comment: No i mean to say inside membership model a relation to order_items.

Comment: You want to access something like, User->membership->order_items ?

Comment: yes i have create  belongs_to relation in membership model

Comment: public function orderItems() {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderItem::class, '_id', 'membership_id')
                    ->select('membership_id', 'expiration_date', 'created_at');
    }

Comment: In membership model that would be wrong, It needs to be something like hasOne or hasMany relationship with the order_items, inside membership model

Comment: This is wrong as far as i know. Because you have a member_id inside order_item, it's not a belongsTo relation here.

Comment: that work fine it give me data but not proper because one membership multiple user can purchase so first of all i need to check user_id in order table.

Comment: So if you first get data from User then User belongsTo a membership and a membership hasOne order_item and also you can chain, an order_item belongsTo order and also order belongsTo a User.

Answer (score 0):

> In membership model create this relation.

```
public function orderitems() {
   return $this->hasOne(OrderItem::class, 'membership_id', 'id');
   //It's upto you to confirm that whether it is a one-to-one or one-to-many relation
}
```

> Then inside controller you can do something like

```
User::with('membership.orderitems')->get();
```

**Updated**

> Alternatively you can create this `hasManyThrough` relation which will give you all order_items related users. Place this relation inside User Model.

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough( //please also check hasOneThrough according to your need
        'App\OrderItem',
        'App\Order',
        'user_id', // Foreign key on order table...
        'order_id', // Foreign key on order_item table...
        'id', // Local key on users table...
        'id' // Local key on order table...
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i was try this, it give me same record in every records order_items its required to check user_id in order .

Comment: So what else you want then ?

Comment: that give "items": [ ] blank.

Comment: `User::with('items')->get();` have you access it in this way ? If there are multiple records so some might not have order_items that will be empty for some users. Also remove the `_` from `id`

Comment: yes,in UserReposirory access like this $this->model->with('items')->get();

Comment: Well I had missed `:` in this relation correct that and check. `Order:class` it was like this make it `Order::class` or simply check updated answer.